# 2015 Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Database Administrators' [fourth moderator election](https://dba.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Paul White]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice as he learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4891768042553344/0).

Please also join me in well-wishing [mrdenny](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34/mrdenny), who is stepping down after almost 4 years of service to this community.

Comment: Congrats, Paul!

Comment: Congrats and thank you @PaulWhite for volunteering !

Comment: I would also like to offer my congratulations. All the best for the future!

Comment: Congratulations Paul.

Comment: Right on, Paul, good to see you made it.  Also, I want to thank Mr. Denny for his service!  I know you're busy traveling the world and taking care of business in the SQL community.  Further, I appreciate those that stepped up and put themselves out there to be considered for this position as well.  I believe that all of the candidates were worthy of this position.  I think I speak for most when I say all of your contributions are very much appreciated and your day will come :)  Congrats again, Paul!!

Comment: Your first actions as moderator already make it seem like a good choice. Congratulations.

Comment: Congrats on being the newest Moderator !!!

Comment: Congratulations Paul. Needless to say you deserve it.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks. I apologise in advance for the newbie mistakes I will make. And thanks to [@mrdenny](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34/mrdenny) for his service.

<sub>Converting this from a comment to an answer, in response to a highly amusing flag :)</sub>